# Nutch No agents listed in 'http.agent.name'

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fetcher: No agents listed in 'http.agent.name' property.
        at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher.checkConfiguration(Fetcher.java:1166)
        at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher.fetch(Fetcher.java:1068)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.run(Crawl.java:135)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.main(Crawl.java:54)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Every time i run ./nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5 . nutch decides to throw this error. I have both my nutch-site.xml & nutch-default.xml set with.

```
 <property>
  <name>http.agent.name</name>
  <value>blah</value>
  </property>
```

Took the description out to make its easier to read. But I fail to see where else the agent name can be specified. if anybody has any advice I would be grateful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

using 1.3? If so make sure you changed nutch-site.xml (and not default) in runtime/local/conf
Changing the conf in NUTCH_HOME/conf won't be copied to the runtime dirs unless you rebuild with ant.

Comment: The mailing list seems not working.I try to subscribe the nutch mailing list a few times,but failed

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the agent name for http.robots.agents also. It worked for me. I didn't get that message thereafter!!!