# Error Nutch No agents listed in 'http.agent.name'

Tags: apache, web-crawler, nutch

I am using nutch2.2.1. Log file is generating following error

ERROR protocol.RobotRulesParser - Agent we advertise (nutch-spider-2.2.1) not listed first in 'http.robots.agents' property!

My nutch-site.xml is (for above property)

```
<property>
<name>http.agent.name</name>
<value>nutch-spider-2.2.1</value>
</property>
```

my nutch-default.xml is

```
<property>
<name>http.agent.name</name>
<value></value>
</property>
```

Where is actual problem? Please guide it clearly(properly explaination).
This question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582934/nutch-no-agents-listed-in-http-agent-name) but I have to bounty this question (if needed) that's why posting it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shoule add the property of "http.robots.agents" and put the value of http.agent.name as the first agent name, and keep the default * at the end of the list.just like:

```
<property>
     <name>http.robots.agents</name>
     <value>nutch-spider-2.2.1,*</value>
</property>
```